# Select Outlook Mail Items in last received order

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to retrieve e-mails from Outlook and paste the content in Excel.

I want to perform filtering (according to the subject) and select the last received ones that meet my condition.

When I try to get item(1) of the folder, it starts somewhere in the middle of the emails.

I tried:

```
For n = 1 To eFolder.Items.Count
    Set objMail = eFolder.Items(n)
    subj = objMail.Subject
    MsgBox (n)
    MsgBox (subj)
    MsgBox (objMail.ReceivedTime)
Next
```

The result is:

- `n` goes from 1 to the total number of mails (54 in my case)
- however, when checking the time when they were received, the order corresponds to: 34,35,..., 54, 33, 43,...,1

I tried `.Items.GetLast` and it works, but how could I go one by one, backward, checking to see whether it matches with the next condition I want to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort on `ReceivedTime` and then loop through them. You may want to read up on [Items.Sort method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort)

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items

    myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

    For Each myItem In myItems
        Debug.Print myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.ReceivedTime
    Next myItem
End Sub
```

Comment: It actually depends on the filters applied to the view. There can be a lot of filters, not only sorted by the `RecievedTime`.

Comment: You are absolutely right @EugeneAstafiev. Fortunately, `RecievedTime` is a very common filter. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The order in which emails are listed on the UI in Outlook doesn't correspond to the order in the `Items` collection. The `Explorer.CurrentView` or `Folder.CurrentView` properties return an object representing the current view.

The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear timeline.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.xml) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

Use `Views` (index), where index is the name of the `View` object or its ordinal value, to return a single `View` object.

However, you can sort items in the collection too. The [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method sorts the collection of items by the specified property.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really clarifying answer.